# setInterval for many canvas to change its rgba

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have many canvas, for each canvas, its just a circle in it and filled with different color, and it will change its rgba within a specific time.

[only one canvas](https://jsfiddle.net/cool21540125/ogmLuzrt/) <- it works

[two canvas](https://jsfiddle.net/cool21540125/hu1kurrx/)  <- it works, with duplicate codes

Now, I have 64 canvas...

I try to write the same scripts one time, but...

it's going crazy after 4~5 seconds and makes me crazy too.

```js
$(function(){
    var c, ctx;
    var cs = $('.demo');
    var t = 1;
    var colors = [
            "rgba(255,0,0,[[opacity]])", 
            "rgba(255,255,0,[[opacity]])",
            "rgba(0,255,0,[[opacity]])",
        ];
        
    for (var i=0; i < cs.length; i++) {
        c = cs[i];
        ctx = c.getContext('2d');
        ctx.arc(100, 100, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        setTimeout(changeRGBA, 0, colors, c, ctx, t, i);
    }

    function changeRGBA(colors, c, ctx, t, i) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        t = (t == 1) ? 0.1 : 1;
        ctx.fillStyle = colors[i].replace("[[opacity]]", t);
        ctx.fill();
        setInterval(changeRGBA, 500, colors, c, ctx, t, i);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<canvas id="demo1" class="demo" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="demo2" class="demo" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="demo3" class="demo" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

How to rewrite the scripts?

Comment: because everytime you call changeRGBA you create another interval. I am assuming you mean timeout, not interval

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I know what the problem is going on now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @epascarello leave comment to point out my question

It works well for my question, just replace setTimeout for setInterval.

But I think it's not good enough, beacuse I repeat typing

`setTimeout(changeRGBA, 0, colors, c, ctx, t, i);`

```js
$(function(){
    var c, ctx;
    var cs = $('.demo');
    var t = 1;
    var colors = [
            "rgba(255,0,0,[[opacity]])", 
            "rgba(255,255,0,[[opacity]])",
            "rgba(0,255,0,[[opacity]])",
        ];
        
    for (var i=0; i < cs.length; i++) {
        c = cs[i];
        ctx = c.getContext('2d');
        ctx.arc(100, 100, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        changeRGBA(colors, c, ctx, t, i);
    }

    function changeRGBA(colors, c, ctx, t, i) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        t = (t == 1) ? 0.1 : 1;
        ctx.fillStyle = colors[i].replace("[[opacity]]", t);
        ctx.fill();
        setTimeout(changeRGBA, 500, colors, c, ctx, t, i);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<canvas id="demo1" class="demo" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="demo2" class="demo" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="demo3" class="demo" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: In the for loop just use changeRGBA( colors, c, ctx, t, i);

Comment: @user700284  Thanks for hinting me. :-)